# RuntimeException ....You must include the platform port before the LWUIT in the classpath

Tags: blackberry, java-me, lwuit, blackberry-simulator, lwuit-form

Please help me, I searched a lot (almost every link & post) but didn't get answer.
I am getting:

```
RuntimeException ....You must include the platform port before the LWUIT in the classpath
```

This error when I run my `lwuit` application on blackberry simulator (which runs fine on `j2me` phones).
In my application at starting exception occurs afterwards application works fine.
Can anyone tell me which all jars should i add in my project.
I tried adding `io_rim` & `ui_rim` project jars in my project but same error.on some changes of jar files, error changes to `ClassNotFoundException` or `IllegalStateException`.
I tried removing `3d`, `m3g` etc. classes from `lwuit.jar`.
After removing these classes it gives `ClassNotFoundException` & after adding these classes in `lwuit.jar` it gives verification error.
Please help me with this problem.
Thanks for your precious time.

Answer (score 1):

Ok porting LWUIT to Blackberry can be a hard road.

I recommend you to take a look on this URLS:

[SUccess in BB LWUIT](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/wsnyder6/archive/2008/07/success_lwuit_o.html)

If this doesn't help, considerate to port your project to CodenameOne

[CodenameOne](http://www.codenameone.com/)